# from python, how to write an integer into a (hex) bytea field

Tags: python, postgresql, plpython

issue is this: in (pl)python code, we've calculated an integer = 26663.
Can easily convert this to hex using hex(myint) = 0x6827

So far so good!

Now, how to write this value -into a concatenation of strings- into a PostgreSQL (v9) bytea field? The DB is UTF8-encoded, if this matters.

EG, neither of these examples will work:

Here, of course, I cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects:

```
rv = plpy.execute(plan, [ (string1 + 6827) ])
```

This one inputs the wrong hex code for 0x6827

```
rv = plpy.execute(plan, [ (string1 + str('6827')) ])
```

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Postgres, but the `hex(n)` function returns a string representation of the numeric value of `n` in hexadecimal. The nicest way in my opinion to concatenate this with a string is to use format strings. For example:

```
rv = plpy.execute(plan, [ ( 'foo %s bar' % hex(6827) ) ] )
```

If the string is really in a variable called `string1`, and you only need to append it with the hex value, then simple concatenation using the + sign will work fine:

```
rv = plpy.execute(plan, [ ( string1 + hex(6827) ) ])
```

This works without conversion because the hex() function returns a string.

If you don't actually want to store a printable string representation, but rather a binary string, use the struct module to create an array of bytes.

```
import struct
bytes = struct.pack('i', 6827) # Ignoring endianness
```

A lot of people are confused about what storing something as "binary" actually means, and since you are using a field type (`bytea`) which seems to be intended for binary storage, maybe this is what you actually want?

The returned value from bytes will be a string that you can either concatenate with another string, or continue to pack more binary values into.

See the [struct module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) for more information!

Comment: thanks for your comment - I'll check out the struct module now. Yes, indeed, I think the struct module may be what I need. This is going into a 'string' of 4 bytes.

Comment: Yes, it looks like struct.pack will do it, but am having a heck of a time sorting through the formatting options; I'm trying to 'pack left', on a little-endian machine - something like struct.pack('i', 26663)
The objective being 4 bytes, I think this kind of output from pack would do the trick: \x00\x00\x68\x27
Can you offer any further guidance?

Comment: This seems to have done it!
`bytes = struct.pack('>l', myinteger)`
It's a bit counterintuitive, though, as this seems to be syntax for big-endianness - while we're on a little-endian machine...